# Find the minimum elevation pixels from an elevation raster using arcpy

Tags: raster, arcpy, arcmap, raster-calculator

I want to create a python script  to find the minimum elevation pixels from an elevation raster (aster,srtm) using arcpy and arcmap 10.1.  The purpose is to reclassify these pixels.
I have tried but I do not have enough knowledge in scripting.

Can somebody please help me ?

Comment: Are you looking for a single value (the lowest elevation point in the entire raster), or multiple values (local low elevations throughout the raster)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Get Raster Properties (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m7000000) to extract minimum elevation values.

```
import arcpy

inputRaster = r'C:\temp\dem.img'

raster = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management (inputRaster, "MINIMUM")
```

To extract the information so that you can use it in a command such as [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) or [Reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) use the following:

```
elevMin = raster.getOutput(0)
```

To put it all together, the following script shows how to find the minimum elevation value and reclassify all values <= (minimum elevation + 300).

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

inputRaster = r'C:\temp\dem.img'

# Get minimum elevation value in DEM
raster = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management (inputRaster, "MINIMUM")
elevMin = float(raster.getOutput(0))

# Convert all values <= elevation min + 300 to 0, else maintain pixel value
outCon = Con(Raster(inputRaster) <= elevMin + 300 , 0, inputRaster)
outCon.save(r'C:\temp\outRaster.img')
```

Comment: yes that right,but that method show me one min only i want all mins from raster

Comment: this is **elevMin = raster.getOutput(0)** output parameter ? i cant to get this

Comment: You have to convert this to type Float to work in the `Con` function.

Answer (score 0):

If your script knowledge is limited have you considered doing this in model builder? The model below will identify the minimum cell value and extract all cells with this value to a new grid.

[image: Extract minimum cell values from a raster]